# Backing up the EFS partitions via adb shell only saves one file

Tags: android, shell, adb, su

So I created a batch file to backup the EFS partition of the OnePlus One via the su in the ADB Shell however;

```
 adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p10 of=/sdcard/modemst1.bin bs=512; if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p11 of=/sdcard/modemst2.bin bs=512"
```

only does the first part of the line before the break. (I have also tried it with && and it hasn't worked also)
I have checked the Su Logs and both commands are appearing... Any idea on what is causing the issue? (Source of the efs partitions is [here - OnePlus Forums](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/guide-backup-restore-efs-partition.278167/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. After downloading and testing a sample from another program I needed to run

```
adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p10 of=/sdcard/modemst1.bin bs=512"
adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p11 of=/sdcard/modemst2.bin bs=512"
```

rather than it being on the same line...